# RDO packstack : losing IP connectivity during installation

Tags: openstack, rdo

I'm trying to install Openstack Mitaka via RDO packstack. I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOlIB323c8s) tutorial. It completely alligns with the official [doc](https://www.rdoproject.org/install/quickstart/).

I'm making sure that I have internet connectivity and that my hostname is resolving (by putting it in the /etc/hosts file). When I install Openstack via packstack --allinone, I see the puppet scripts executing but after a while it hangs.

When I then try to ping my Centos machine it fails. I have no clue why this is as I verified the ping worked before I started the install. It must happen during the packstack installation process.

I have tried now 4 times, reinstalling Centos and Packstack and the behaviour is consistent. I'm running on Virtualbox and my network is in Bridge mode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that packstack during installation changed my IP address. Not sure why or how, but it was different at some point in time. So the key is to set a static IP address in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` file and also ensure your hostname resolves (by setting it in the `/etc/hosts` file)